# Android Studio64 not starting

Tags: android-studio

This might sound a little foolish but I am not getting to start my Studio64.exe. I have updated JDK,JRE and even reinstalled Android  Studio. Even after all this I am not getting to start Studio64.I can start Studio.exe(x86).

These are my environment variables:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky, I have don a clean install(without previous config) of Studio using the latest version and it works now.